# Php: syntax error, unexpecte ';'

Tags: php

Please I can't figure out what is wrong with this line :

```
    echo "<tr><td>".substr($row['Vehicule_ID'], 0, - (strlen($row['Marque']) + 1)."</td><td>".$row['Marque']."</td><td>".$row['Modele']."</td><td>".$row['Couleur']."</td></tr>";
```

I have this error :

[Unexpected ';'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeDfk.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Thank you @u_mulder this is not realy applicable in this case, but it's very helpful for furthur need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing closing bracket after `+ 1`. It is the closing bracket corresponding to the opening one of `substr(`.

And so PHP finds the semi-colon as being inside the last argument of `substr`, which is a syntax error.